# Need help accessing JSON array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, each

Objective: This code collects an array JSONAPIS and passes the APIS into a $.each() loop. Then JSON data field are evaluated in if statements and used to calculate precip. How do I access the JSONAPIS from the obj.
Main issue: obj.daily.data.length is undefined on the daily array member. The obj should contain one of the API calls and the JSON dataset to use. Instead it contains keyword like abort, always, promise which I am not familiar how to use. What would access the result JSON object property?

```
var listAPIs = "";
var darkForecastAPI = [];
var result = [];
var JSONAPIS = [];

$.each(numDaysAPITimes, function(a, time) {
    var darkForecastAPI = /*"http://api.wunderground.com/api/" + currentAPIKey + "/history_" + time + "/q/" + state + "/" + city +".json?callback=?"; */
        "http://api.forecast.io/forecast/" + currentAPIKey + "/" + city + time + "?callback=?";
    //https://api.forecast.io/forecast/APIKEY/LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,TIME
    JSONAPIS.push($.getJSON(darkForecastAPI, {
        tags: "WxAPI[" + i + "]", //Is this tag the name of each JSON page? I tried to index it incase this is how to refer to the JSON formatted code from the APIs.
        tagmode: "any",
        format: "json"
    }));
});
$.when.apply($, JSONAPIS).done(function(result) { /*no log simply an array */
    var eachPrecipSum = 0.0;
    var totalPrecipSinceDate = 0.0;
    alert(result);

    $.each(result, function(d, obj) {
    console.log(obj);
        for (var c = 0; c <= obj.daily.data.length - 1; c++) {
            if (obj.daily.data[c].precipIntensity >= 0.0000 && obj.daily.data[c].precipType == "rain") /*Number(result.history.dailysummary.precipm, result.history.dailysummary.rain*/ {
                eachPrecipSum = result[d].daily.data[c].precipIntensity;
                totalPrecipSinceDate = eachPrecipSum + totalPrecipSinceDate; ///Write mean precip
                alert(Math.round(eachPrecipSum * 10000) / 10000);
                $("body").append("p").text("There has been as least a total of " + Math.round(totalPrecipSinceDate * 10000) / 10000 + " inches per hour of rain at the location in the last " + userDataDatePick + " days")

            } else if (obj.daily.data[c].precipIntensity >= 0.0000 && obj.daily.data[c].precipType != "rain") {
                alert("There is was no rain on ____" /*+ result.history.dailysummary.mon + "/" + result.history.dailysummary.mday + "/" + result.history.dailysummary.year*/ );
            }
        }
    });
});
numDaysAPITimes = 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

`$.when` doesn't take array as input

Since you are passing an array that isn't  itself a promise it is likely firing immediately and therefore ahead of all the ajax calls completing

Need to change to

```
$.when.apply(null, JSONAPIS).done...
```

Comment: Put this in the same context?

Comment: Like this? `$.when.apply(null, JSONAPIS).done(function(result) {`

Comment: This turned out one object from the list, but it built a second item called success and another similar to the first code I had with keywords. What do you think happened or needs to be done? It should make three JSON objs

Comment: look at this inside done  `console.log(arguments)` should be array of all the ajax responses

Comment: This is what happened. `0: Object
1: "success"
2: Object` You mean to add console.log(arguments) somewhere in the code? Does it show a popup?

Comment: will log to browser console

Comment: These are log results on obj 2: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined(anonymous function) @ rainWatch.js:65p.extend.each @ jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2(anonymous function) @ rainWatch.js:63p.Callbacks.k @ jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2p.Callbacks.l.fireWith @ jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2p.extend.when.g @ jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2p.Callbacks.k @ jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2p.Callbacks.l.fireWith @ jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2y @ jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2p.ajaxTransport.send.c.onload.c.onreadystatechange @ jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2`

Comment: will have to loop over all of the arguments and then loop over all the results within each argument's array. So wrap another `$.each` around the one you have

Comment: Is this what you mean? : `$.each(result, function(e, unwrap) {
        $.each(result[e], function(d, obj) {
        console.log(obj);
            for (var c = 0; c <= obj.daily.data.length - 1; c++) {`

Comment: I am not following where exactly. I have several $.each() you must understand.

Comment: Need to rest for the night. Will check this in morning. Thank you, it looks like I have made some final progress on this!